# Evaluating a Scala List[Either] into a Boolean

Tags: scala, playframework

I am using scanamo to query a dynamodb and all i want to do is check that the db actually exists. I'm not really concerned with the record I get back, just that there were no errors. For the query part I'm using this:

```
trait DynamoTestTrait extends AbstractDynamoConfig {  def test(): Future[List[Either[DynamoReadError, T]]] =    ScanamoAsync.exec(client)table.consistently.limit(1).scan())}
```

that returns the Future List. I want to evaluate the first? item in the list and just return true if it is not a read error.

I thought this would work but it doesn't:

```
 val result = test() match {
      case r: DynamoReadError => Future.successful(false)
      case r: Registration    => Future.successful(true)
    }
```

I'm new to scala so struggling with return types and things. This is a Play api call so i need to evaluate that boolen future at some point. With something like this:

```
 def health = Action {
    val isHealthy = h.testDynamo()
    val b: Boolean = Await.result(isHealthy, scala.concurrent.duration.Duration(5, "seconds"))
    Ok(Json.toJson(TestResponse(b.toString)))
  }
```

I think this is probably wrong also as i don't want to use Await but i can't get async to work either. 
Sorry, i'm kind of lost.

When i try to evaluate result i only get a message about the Future:

```
{
"status": 500,
"message": "Future(<not completed>) (of class scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise)"
}
```

Comment: What is in result? I'm not entirely sure how your database call works. But the syntax you have is that result will be what's matched in the cases and then returned into the result val. So it most likely is either true or false? Could you check at least what result is?

Comment: I can't seem to check on what any of the intermediate values are because they are futures. not sure how i can do that.

Comment: read Tim's comment and you'll see what to do. I forgot to say that the Result is a future. To check the Future (result) this is what you'd do val futureResult = Await(result, 30 seconds); println(futureResult); But Tim's solution is better and checks all your futures. If you don't understand Left and Right.. Right is basically tries to check if it' Sucessful..so then True. And Left for when it fails. Again, check Tim's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is a `Future` so you can't test the result without doing something like `Await.result` (as you do later). What you can do is modify the result returned by the `Future` to be the result you need.

In your case you can do this:

```
test().map(_.headOption.forall(_.isRight))
```

This will return `Future[Boolean]` which you can then use in your `Await.result` call.

Here is how it works:

- `map` calls a function on the result of the `Future`, which is type `List[Either[DynamoReadError, T]]` and returns a new `Future` that gives the result of that function call.
- `_.headOption` takes the head of the list and returns an `Option[Either[DynamoReadError, T]]`. This is `Some(...)` if there are one or more elements in the list, or `None` if the list is empty.
- `forall` checks the contents of the  `Option` and returns the result of the test on that option. If the `Option` is `None` then it returns `true`.
- `_.isRight` tests the value `Either[...]` and returns `true` if the value is `Right[...]` and `false` if it is `Left[...]`.

This does what you specified, but perhaps it would be better to check if any of the results failed, rather than just the first one? If so, it is actually a bit simpler:

```
test().map(_.forall(_.isRight))
```

This checks that all the entries in the `List` are `Right`, and fails as soon as a `Left` is found.

The problem with returning this from `Play` is a separate issue and should probably be in a separate question.

Comment: my thinking was that if i used the limit(1) on the scanamo call i would only ever get back 1 or 0 records

Comment: thanks for the help - this definitely does what i need it to do with the Future result. Now i have to spawn two more questions - one is how to deal with the Play response as async and the other issue is that if i get the name of the dynamo table wrong then it fails instead of returning a Left in the call.